# Mysql - Sum is not returning results when making a pivot

Tags: mysql, select, sum, pivot

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    r.id_account AS 'account_id',
    a.name AS 'account_name',
    r.id_status_g 'status_id',
    sg.name AS 'status_name',
    r.transaction_type AS 'transtype_id',
    tt.name AS 'transtype_name',
    COUNT(r.id) AS 'count',
    r.currency_code,
    SUM(r.amount/100) AS 'amount'
FROM transaction_r r, account a, transaction_type tt, status_g sg
WHERE
    r.id_account = a.id AND
    r.transaction_type = tt.id AND
    r.id_status_g = sg.id AND
    r.c_date >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    r.c_date <= '2015-10-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    r.id_status_g, r.currency_code
ORDER BY
    r.id_account, r.id_status_g;
```

Which outputs the following result:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+
| account_id | account_name | status_id | status_name | transtype_id | transtype_name | count | currency_code | amount |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+
|          8 | testing      |         1 | Approved    |            1 | Sale           |     1 | USD           |     20 |
|          8 | testing      |         3 | Declined    |            1 | Sale           |     1 | USD           |     20 |
|          8 | testing      |         4 | Error       |            1 | Sale           |    10 | USD           |    200 |
|          8 | testing      |         5 | Refunded    |            1 | Sale           |     1 | USD           |     20 |
|          8 | testing      |         6 | Chargeback  |            1 | Sale           |     1 | USD           |     20 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+----------------+-------+---------------+--------+------+-------+---------------+--------+
```

The information above is correct, but I'd like to return only one row per currency code and account id, so I did a pivot using the following query:

```
SELECT
    a.name AS 'account_name',
    r.transaction_type AS 'transtype_id',
    tt.name AS 'transtype_name',
    r.currency_code,
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 4, 1,0)) END AS 'error',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 3, 1, 0)) END AS 'declined',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 6, 1, 0)) END AS 'chargeback',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 5, 1, 0)) END AS 'refunded',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 1, 1, 0)) END AS 'approved',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 4, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_error',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 3, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_declined',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 6, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_chargeback',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 5, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_refunded',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 1, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_approved'
FROM transaction_r r, account a, transaction_type tt, status_g sg
WHERE
    r.id_account = a.id AND
    r.transaction_type = tt.id AND
    r.id_status_g = sg.id AND
    r.c_date >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    r.c_date <= '2015-10-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    r.id_account, r.currency_code
```

Which returns exactly the way I want, however only the first sum each set of cases work, the rest of them return nulls.

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| account_name | transtype_id | transtype_name | currency_code | error | declined | chargeback | refunded | approved | amount_error | amount_declined | amount_chargeback | amount_refunded | amount_approved |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| testing      |            1 | Sale           | USD           |    10 | NULL     | NULL       | NULL     | NULL     |          200 | NULL            | NULL              | NULL            | NULL            |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

If I make a different grouping, I can see a row per amount sum, and each one of them have a correct sum value with the rest on null (a row has the correct sum for approved amount and the rest returning null, the following one for declined amount and so on)

If the sums were wrong I'd expect none of them working, same for the table joining, but the first of each set of case work, which gets me confused. Is there a problem with the way I'm implementing the query? This is the first pivot attempt I make in MySQL and any feedback would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're close - I've taken a stab at explaining the issue below.  I haven't tested it - am happy to if you post a SQLfiddle.com with a sample schema etc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested - but I believe this is what you want...

Remember the `SELECT` is working against the result of the `GROUP BY`... so `r.id_*` is kinda meaningless (in that non/post-aggregate context)...

The `SUM()` however is aggregating - the content of it *is* applied against every record (not just the output of the `GROUP BY`.

So you're correct to have put the `IF(...)` inside of them (each `SUM()` I mean).  Loose the conditional on the outside (the `CASE` you crafted) and move the `r.id_account` into the existing `IF(...)` and you should be golden.

You were close :)

```
SELECT
    a.name AS 'account_name',
    r.transaction_type AS 'transtype_id',
    tt.name AS 'transtype_name',
    r.currency_code,
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4, 1,0)) AS 'error',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3, 1, 0)) AS 'declined',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6, 1, 0)) AS 'chargeback',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5, 1, 0)) AS 'refunded',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'approved',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) AS 'amount_error',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) AS 'amount_declined',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) AS 'amount_chargeback',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) AS 'amount_refunded',
    SUM(IF(r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) AS 'amount_approved'
FROM transaction_r r, account a, transaction_type tt, status_g sg
WHERE
    r.id_account = a.id AND
    r.transaction_type = tt.id AND
    r.id_status_g = sg.id AND
    r.c_date >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    r.c_date <= '2015-10-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    r.id_account, r.currency_code
```

Comment: Both you and the OP has more fields in the select list which are not subject of a grouping function, than in the group by list.

Comment: @Shadow MySQL allows that, unless you turn on the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option.

Comment: Yeah - MySQL allows a few things beyond what other engines do.

Comment: @Shadow despite of the fact Barmar is correct, you're right on making the query 'compliant' with standards it's a good practice and I'll take it into consideration, thanks for notice it :)

Comment: @wally you're absolutely right, thanks :) even when it was adding nothing to the result, why was the case returning nulls despite the condition does exists? Is it because of the case evaluates the condition for all of the fields which was causing to return nulls on the non matching fields? and off topic what did you do to edit the table output format of the post? That's the way I wanted them to look like, I guess I was close on that too :P

Comment: @Juan Regarding the NULLs - yes, because the case never evaluated (you had no "default"/"else" section) it literally had "no value to return".  Ergo NULL.  //  Regarding the formatting: I indented by 4 characters (alternatively you can select it in the textarea too [in your browser] and click the "{}" button on the toolbar).  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I belive the problem is that you have added some fields in the select list that are not part of any grouping function, such as sum() and are not in the group by list either:

```
SELECT
    a.name AS 'account_name',
    r.transaction_type AS 'transtype_id',
    tt.name AS 'transtype_name',
    r.currency_code,
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 4, 1,0)) END AS 'error',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 3, 1, 0)) END AS 'declined',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 6, 1, 0)) END AS 'chargeback',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 5, 1, 0)) END AS 'refunded',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 1, 1, 0)) END AS 'approved',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 4 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 4, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_error',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 3 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 3, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_declined',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 6 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 6, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_chargeback',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 5 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 5, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_refunded',
    CASE WHEN r.id_account = 8 AND r.id_status_g = 1 THEN SUM(IF (r.id_status_g = 1, ROUND(r.amount/100, 2), 0)) END AS 'amount_approved'
FROM transaction_r r, account a, transaction_type tt, status_g sg
WHERE
    r.id_account = a.id AND
    r.transaction_type = tt.id AND
    r.id_status_g = sg.id AND
    r.c_date >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    r.c_date <= '2015-10-09 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    a.name, r.transaction_type, tt.name, r.currency_code
```

I know that mysql allows for this syntax, however, if you omit those fields, then mysql will take the values for these fields from the 1st record in the "physical" order of records that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: I actually tried to add grouping fields to the `group by` before posting, but as @barmar suggested on the comments below, MySQL actually allows this by default and it made no changes to the result